# ORA-06502 from query that works in standalone SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-06502

I am getting the ORA-06502 error while calling this query from PL/SQL.
However if I try from the SQL prompt it is working.

From the SQL prompt this gives the expected output:

```
 SELECT *
  FROM
  (
   SELECT
       COL.BAN,
       MAX (COL.COL_ACTV_CODE) AS COL_ACTV_CODE,
       MAX (TO_CHAR(COL.COL_ACTV_DATE,'MM')) AS COL_ACTV_DATE
   FROM
       COLLECTION               COL,
       COLLECTION_ACTIVITIES    CAC
   WHERE (CAC.SEVERITY_LEVEL , TO_CHAR(COL.COL_ACTV_DATE,'YYYYMM')) IN
        (SELECT
               MAX(CAC.SEVERITY_LEVEL),
               MAX(TO_CHAR(COL.COL_ACTV_DATE, 'YYYYMM'))
          FROM
               COLLECTION               COL,
               COLLECTION_ACTIVITIES    CAC
          WHERE
               COL.COL_ACTV_CODE    = CAC.COL_ACTIVITY_CODE
          GROUP BY  TO_CHAR (COL.COL_ACTV_DATE , 'YYYYMM')
         )
    GROUP BY  COL.BAN
    ORDER BY  TO_CHAR (COL.COL_ACTV_DATE , 'YYYYMM') DESC
     )
     PIVOT
    (
       MAX( COL_ACTV_CODE)
     FOR COL_ACTV_DATE in ('01' as "JAN", '02' as "FEB", '03' as "MAR"));

       BAN J F M A M J J A S O N D
---------- - - - - - - - - - - - -
  90314228                 W
  90314009     K
  90314748                     E
  90314568                   E
  90314328                 W
```

But from PL/SQL:

```
BEGIN

STMT_STR := 'CREATE TABLE ACD_COL_ST
            PCTUSED 90
            NOLOGGING
            AS
 SELECT *
  FROM
  (
   SELECT
       COL.BAN,
       MAX (COL.COL_ACTV_CODE) AS COL_ACTV_CODE,
       MAX (TO_CHAR(COL.COL_ACTV_DATE,'MM')) AS COL_ACTV_DATE
   FROM
       COLLECTION               COL,
       COLLECTION_ACTIVITIES    CAC
   WHERE (CAC.SEVERITY_LEVEL , TO_CHAR(COL.COL_ACTV_DATE,'YYYYMM')) IN
        (SELECT
               MAX(CAC.SEVERITY_LEVEL),
               MAX(TO_CHAR(COL.COL_ACTV_DATE, 'YYYYMM'))
          FROM
               COLLECTION               COL,
               COLLECTION_ACTIVITIES    CAC
          WHERE
               COL.COL_ACTV_CODE    = CAC.COL_ACTIVITY_CODE
          GROUP BY  TO_CHAR (COL.COL_ACTV_DATE , 'YYYYMM')
         )
    GROUP BY  COL.BAN
    ORDER BY  TO_CHAR (COL.COL_ACTV_DATE , 'YYYYMM') DESC
     )
     PIVOT
    (
       MAX( COL_ACTV_CODE)
     FOR COL_ACTV_DATE in ('01' as "JAN", '02' as "FEB", '03' as "MAR"))';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE STMT_STR;

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('An error was encountered creating table ACD_COL_ST'||SQLCODE||'  - ERROR - '||SQLERRM);
END;
COMMIT;
```

I get an error:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Comment: What is the input you give to your query for `&1`? And could you simplify to a smaller query where you still get your PL error?

Comment: im not really sure about this, but have you tried changing `&1` to `:1`. & is a feature of SQL*Plus for substitution variables.You should refrain from using it in PL/SQL, though Im not quite sure if that solves your problem.Hopes this helps

Comment: i updated the question with a simpler query

Comment: &1 works in PL/SQL too

Comment: Welcome to SO! In its current state, your question is nearly impossible to answer - please take the time to format your question in a sensible way by [edit] ing it and include sample data, therefore making it a [MCVE].

Comment: You haven't shown any PL/SQL code so it's impossible to know what you are doing wrong. It may not even be this query (or however you are handling the results it returns; the query itself isn't doing anything that can cause that error), it would be something completely unrelated elsewhere in your block.

Comment: Added the pl/sql block.I am trying to create this table and then retrieve from this table

Comment: You haven't shown how STMT_STR is declared. Presumably that's just too small for the length of the dynamic statement. Or there's a problem with how you're calling this. (Creating a table on the fly is generally a bad idea; maybe this should be a view, or a materialized view, or a PL/SQL collection depending on what you're dong with it)

Answer (score 0):

I just check the code. Before we can answer can u plz tell me why you are creating table on the run time using Dynamic SQL. It is not possible to creat the table first and then INSERT into it using SIMPLER SQL than PLSQL. Anyhow i see in you code that there are single quotes only for strings. We need to use '' for ' in dynamic query. Please see below query i dont have workspace with me right now so cant validate the query. Pardon any syntactical error.

```
DECLARE
STMT_STR LONG;
BEGIN
STMT_STR := 
        'CREATE TABLE ACD_COL_ST                        
        AS 
        SELECT *  
        FROM  
        (   
        SELECT       
        COL.BAN,       
        MAX (COL.COL_ACTV_CODE) AS COL_ACTV_CODE,       
        MAX (TO_CHAR(COL.COL_ACTV_DATE,''MM'')) AS COL_ACTV_DATE   
        FROM       
        COLLECTION               COL,       
        COLLECTION_ACTIVITIES    CAC   
        WHERE (CAC.SEVERITY_LEVEL , TO_CHAR(COL.COL_ACTV_DATE,''YYYYMM'')) IN        
        (SELECT               
        MAX(CAC.SEVERITY_LEVEL),               
        MAX(TO_CHAR(COL.COL_ACTV_DATE, ''YYYYMM''))          
        FROM               
        COLLECTION               COL,               
        COLLECTION_ACTIVITIES    CAC          
        WHERE               
        COL.COL_ACTV_CODE    = CAC.COL_ACTIVITY_CODE          
        GROUP BY  TO_CHAR (COL.COL_ACTV_DATE , ''YYYYMM'')         
        )    
        GROUP BY  COL.BAN    
        ORDER BY  TO_CHAR (COL.COL_ACTV_DATE , ''YYYYMM'') DESC     
        )     
        PIVOT    
        (       
        MAX( COL_ACTV_CODE)     
        FOR COL_ACTV_DATE in (''01'' as JAN, ''02'' as FEB, ''03'' as MAR))';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE STMT_STR;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('An error was encountered creating table ACD_COL_ST'||SQLCODE||'  - ERROR - '||SQLERRM);
END;
```

Comment: LONG has been deprecated for ages; you should use CLOB instead, though for this the query will fit in VARCHAR2 anyway. I think the escaped quotes are a red herring, the OP just added the PL/SQL bits to the question around the existing SQL statement. They might be using the alternate quoting mechanism, which would be simpler than escaping the quotes.

Comment: Yes maybe but in this scenario for dynamic SQL missing quotes will be an issue

Comment: It wouldn't give that error though. Doesn't hurt to mention it of course.